# Cookies only work when in a certain directory

Tags: php, cookies

I have set up a simple login page on `http://mywebsite.com/control`. When you login, it places a cookie called `user` on your computer. To set the cookie I simply use:

```
setcookie("user", $_POST['IGN']);
```

When I am on the directory `/control`, it works fine. For example, if I use the code:

```
echo $_Cookie['user'];
```

it echos out the cookie information. However, if I do this on any page that is not in the `/control` directory, it says:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /var/www/other/vars.php on line 16
```

Line 16 is where it echos. This is an image of the cookie information in Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
setcookie("user", $_POST['IGN'],0,'/');
```

if you want cookie to be visible in the whole domain

You should also use:

```
echo $_COOKIE['user'];
```

with capital letters

You should also read more about setting cookies at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php - by default cookies are set only for directory where you set cookie. That's why you need to add as 4th parameter '/'

Answer (score 1):

It does that because you are not setting the path parameter when you set your cookie, and by default, PHP will take the current directoy you're in.

Try this.

```
setcookie("cookiename", "value", time()+3600, "/", "mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: I assume I change .mywebsite.com with ftb.chipperyman.com right?

Comment: Yes, you could actually change it to just `chipperyman.com`, which would allow the cookie to be used across all subdomains too